# execute the NETSH WLAN SHOW ALL command with pauses

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a batch program of which one function is to show all properties of the wlan, however, when executing the command `NETSH WLAN SHOW ALL` all output goes by so fast half of it can't be read. I was wondering if there is a way of adding pauses during the output like you can do with the dir command

Comment: Have you tried `netsh wlan show all | more `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **MC ND** propose to you :

```
netsh wlan show all | more
```

And you have also the possibilty to save it as text file and you read it after :

```
@echo off
netsh wlan show all > Tmp.txt
Cmd /U /C Type Tmp.txt > WlanInfos.txt
Del Tmp.txt
start WlanInfos.txt
```